# How to disable field from View on Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am struggling trying to disable it, but I am using the same `form` for two different views, and on one view I need to disable or readonly a field, how can I reach this?

I reach this so far on **VIEWS.py**

```
obj = ModelUpdate.objects.first()
field_object = ModelUpdate._meta.get_field('myfield')
field_value = getattr(obj, field_object.attname)
```

Comment: It is not clear how does your view/forms look like. Where do you want to exclude a certain field, and where live this piece of code is in your views.py etc, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want to re-use a form in two separate views but have one version have a readonly field? If so, you could either have two versions of the form in your `forms.py` file, if the form code is not particularly long, or you could add some sort of check in the `def __init__` of the form to set the field as readonly under a certain condition:

```
my_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want two separate forms, you could do this:

```py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   ...

   def __init__(self, my_field_is_read_only=False, *args, **kwargs):
      super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

      if my_field_is_read_only:
         self.fields['my_field'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Comment: Can you write more code please? it is not well specified, thank you! I have 1 form, but 2 views are using it

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: I cannot put it on forms.py due to I am using it with two different views.... (I am trying to pass a parameter from views to forms)

Comment: Well your two views would use it as MyForm() and MyForm(my_field_is_read_only=True)

Comment: they just user reverse() thats the problem...

Comment: `reverse()` gets a URL from a name, it isn't actually the view

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance.

```
class AbstractForm(forms.Form):
    # General fields

class AllEditableForm(AbstractForm):
    # The field which we will allow to edit
    target_field = forms.XXXXField()
    
class OneFieldReadOnly(AbstractForm):
    # Make the field read only
    target_field = forms.XXXXField(disabled=True)
```